# SQL: Combine results from two sets and display using Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pivot values from a query as shown in the diagram:

[image: Pivot Results]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: SQL Management Studio. The code in the image is just an example of what I am trying to achieve but don't know how using pivots for patients and weighs.

Comment: @TonyAnthony I'm assuming you mean "SQL Server Management Studio" or "SSMS".  If so then really you are using Microsoft SQL Server as your DBMS.

Comment: Yes SSMS is what I'm using as my DBMS

Comment: What I am trying to do is take two columns (No of Patients and Weights) from two tables and pivot the results so that they appear as '1 (14)' where the '1' represents number of patients and the (14) for the weight. Thanks for your help

Comment: "SSMS" is **not** a DBMS - it's a client tool to _connect_ to a DBMS. But as it only supports Microsoft SQL Server it's safe to assume you are using MS SQL Server.

Comment: Okay! Now we have this finer detail ironed out, is there a solution to the question I asked?